# How should a custom segue support an unwind to a viewcontroller earlier in the call chain?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have a storyboarded app using segues without a navigation controller.  We have a simple custom segue like the code below that works fine for normal cases.  However we have a situation where after invoking a chain of view controllers A->B->C we’d sometimes like C to unwind directly back to A.  This works fine with the built-in transitions as UIKit seems to dismiss the intervening controller without any trouble, properly showing a transition from C back to A.

However in my custom segue I am not certain if or how I should dismiss the intervening view controllers. Assume that the code below knows both that it is unwinding and that the destination view controller is not the one presenting the source view controller.  Here is what I’ve tried:

1) If I simply leave the code as is seems to work fine!  However I get errors “Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions” for view controller C.
2) If I change the code to dismiss view controller B first I see the transition to B.  I don’t see any way to suppress this.

From what I've read the unbalanced calls error comes up often when you have overlapping calls to transitions.  However I don't see how that could be the case here since UIKit is dismissing them (presumably).  I've also tried dispatching the completion work to the main thread (to try to get it into the next run loop) but no change.

```
class MyCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform()
    {
        let sourceView = sourceViewController.view
        let destView = destinationViewController.view
        let unwinding = // …

        // Put the destination view on top
        sourceView.superview?.insertSubview(destView, aboveSubview: sourceView)

        // Do the animation
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { complete in
        } ) { (Finished) -> Void in
            if unwinding {
                // calling this on presenter or presentee is equivalent
                self.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```